# Is it possible to make changes in the existing column in a table for sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created one application which is live in play store it has 3 tables in that i would like to add two more columns for a table and delete a column from another table.If i do this and update it to playstore will it cause any effect for the existing users db or they want to uninstall the app to get these new changes?
If there is any good method which can be used to update the tables without affecting the user's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **[onUpgrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int))**

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
>   should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else
>   it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

**Example**

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 3) {
              db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME  + " ADD COLUMN mobile_no INTEGER;");
              db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME  + " ADD COLUMN phone_no INTEGER;");
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Nidhun Kumar I'd suggest having a read of [SQL As Understood By SQLite - ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) in regard to restrictions.